# Cómo hacer que mi campo input de tipo timepicker se muestre vacío en mi pantalla

Tags: javascript, cshtml

Tengo un campo input de tipo timepicker, en este campo me trae la hora actual, pero yo no quiero que me muestre la hora actual, si no que se me muestre vacío, y ya hasta que me sitúe en el campo y de clic ahora si ya me muestre la hora actual, anexo codigo:

En el JS tengo esto:

```
$("#txtHoraInicio").timepicker({ minuteStep: 1, showSeconds: true, 
  timeFormat: 'H:mm:ss p', disableFocus: true, icons: { up: 'fa fa-chevron- 
     up', down: 'fa fa-chevron-down' } }).on('focus', function () {
        

    $("#txtHoraInicio").timepicker('showWidget');

    });
  
    $(".HoraInicioConTrigger").click(function () {

        $("#txtHoraInicio").timepicker('showWidget');
 
    });
```

En el cshtml tengo esto:

```
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
                            <div style="float:right;width:-300px;margin-top:0px;">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.HoraInicio, new { id = "txtHoraInicio", placeholder = "Hora Inicio", @class = "form-control"})
                            </div>
                            <span class="input-group-addon HoraInicioConTrigger">
                                <i class="fa fa-clock-o bigger-110"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Espero puedan apoyarme, saludos.

Comment: Por favor agrega el codigo que llevas hecho

Comment: Te recomendaría que mire https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask para qué tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, haz el recorrido para entender como funciona obtener tu primera medalla http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges

Comment: @Dany, conoce los [magic-links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/149992), con los que en comentarios  puedes enviar a los usuarios a la ayuda, como [ask] o [mcve] escribiendo mucho menos.